# Knox Gateway database connector

Tags: hadoop, knox-gateway, apache-knox

Is it possible to write DB connector using Knox Provider extension?
I want Knox to expose endpoint in response to which Knox would put to or get from database records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you want to connect and what functionality you want to add. Currently, Knox support HTTP and Websockets protocols so if you are using JDBC to connect then that will not work. If you are using JDBC over HTTP (e.g. beeline) then that might work. Here are few links to Knox documentation
[User Guide](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-1-4-0/user-guide.html#Externalized+Provider+Configurations) 
[Dev Guide](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-1-4-0/dev-guide.html#Providers)